# OpenCV c++ API VideoCapture not working with video files

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently using OpenCV(4.5.1-dev) c++ api to try to read frames from a mp4 .video file. I keep getting error "can not open video file". I compile open cv with

```
-DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF
```

as suggested in OpenCV readme.txt. The minimum reproducible code is

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(video_path, cv::CAP_V4L);
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
    std::cerr << "trying to open video file at: " << video_path << std::endl;
    CV_Error(cv::Error::StsError, "Can not open Video file");
}
    
for(int frameNum = 0; frameNum < cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); frameNum++)
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get the next frame from video
    frames.push_back(frame);
}
```

where for video_path, I tried both absolute and relative path. Neither works. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the actual value of `video_path` and why do you think V4L will read video *files*? video devices on linux (v4l) are represented by files but those are actually devices, not files containing data.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz video_path is given by "/home/.../.../.../1.mp4" and when I installed OpenCV, the videoio options only v4l is "YES". Another post said you should specify the io device, that's why I put v4l

Comment: why are you compiling without FFMPEG? where is that suggested and what is it supposed to solve? you should want ffmpeg if you need to read video files. you have been following bad advice.